# How to connect 4 fan coils with one wall control thermostat?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, thermostat, ceiling-fan, fans

I have 4 fan coils (Sabiana sk-22)and I want to connect them with one wall control thermostat. How can I do?

Comment: What is the amps per fan?

Comment: You are looking at a total amperage of 1.28 (.32 * 4). If you are using a low voltage thermostat, that could be too high for the contact terminals of the thermostat.